# Get attribute from different RSS Feeds Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, rss

I have to extract the author of articles written in the RSS feeds, the problem is that one RSS has the attribute of the author name listed as *dc:creator* and the other as *author* (code below). Any way on how i can make my query dynamic for both cases ?

Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE feed.usp_importXML(@file VARCHAR(8000))
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)

        SET @Query ='
            DECLARE @xmlFile as XML
            SET @xmlFile =(SELECT CONVERT(XML,BulkColumn) as BulkColumn
            FROM OPENROWSET (BULK  '''+@file+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t)
            INSERT INTO feed.tempXML (source, title,link,author,[date])
            SELECT
            source = t.value (''../link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                title = t.value (''title[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                link = t.value (''./link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                author = t.value(''(*:creator)[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)''),
                [date] = t.value(''pubDate[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)'')
            FROM @xmlFile.nodes(''/rss/channel/item'') AS xTable(t);'

            EXEC(@Query)
    END
GO
```

RSS 1:

```
<item>
                    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.espnfc.com/story/3154621/wojciech-szczesny-completes-transfer-to-juventus-from-arsenal3154621</guid>
                    <title><![CDATA[Wojciech Szczesny completes transfer to Juventus from Arsenal]]></title>

                    <description>
                        &lt;img style=&quot;float: left; margin-right: 10px;&quot; src=&quot;http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/1002/r134626_1296x729_16-9.jpg&amp;amp;w=100&amp;amp;h=80&amp;amp;scale=crop&amp;amp;site=espnfc&quot; /&gt;<![CDATA[Douglas Costa hopes to evolve as a player with Juventus and gain recognition for Brazil&apos;s World Cup squad next year. 
Juventus have completed the signing of Wojciech Szczesny from Arsenal for a fee of &amp;#8364;12.2 million.
Poland goalkeeper Szczesny underwent his medical in Turin on Tuesday and officially became a Juventus player on Wednesday in a deal that could rise to &amp;#8364;15.3 million, depending on performance.
The 27-year-old, who spent the last two seasons on loan at Roma, has signed a four-year contract for the Bianconeri, where he is expected to be understudy to Italy No. 1 Gianlugi Buffon in the coming...]]>
                    </description>

                    <link>http://www.espnfc.com/story/3154621/wojciech-szczesny-completes-transfer-to-juventus-from-arsenal</link>
                    <pubDate>Wed, 19 Jul 2017 06:19:00 PDT</pubDate>

                    <enclosure length="150" url="http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/1002/r134626_1296x729_16-9.jpg&amp;amp;w=100&amp;amp;h=80&amp;amp;scale=crop&amp;amp;site=espnfc" type="image/jpeg" />

                    <category>Story</category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Transfers]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Juventus]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Arsenal]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Wojciech Szczesny]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[English Premier League]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Italian Serie A]]></category>

                    <dc:creator>Ben Gladwell</dc:creator>
                </item>
```

RSS 2:

```
-<item>

<title>Sampdoria Striker Patrick Schick Could Be Set to Join Inter After Collapse of Juventus Deal</title>

<link>http://www.90min.com/posts/5285895-sampdoria-striker-patrick-schick-could-be-set-to-join-inter-after-collapse-of-juventus-deal?utm_source=RSS</link>

<author>Callum Rice-Coates</author>

<guid isPermaLink="false">d5a2ba8b504a22fcdb405ec687f91956</guid>

<description>Sampdoria striker Patrick Schick could be on the verge of a move to Inter after a proposed deal to join Juventus fell through. Ginaluca Di Marzio has reported that the Czech forward's representatives have met with the Inter hierarchy to discuss the details of the potential transfer. According to the Italian journalist, Schick, who found the net 11 times in 32 Serie A appearances last season, 'could soon enjoy a new experience at Inter.' #Calciomercato | #Inter, incontro in corso con la...</description>

<media:thumbnail type="image/jpg" url="https://images0.minutemediacdn.com/production/912x516/596f80ed6bd5c5594b000001.jpg?main_image=true&imageType=.jpg"/>

<pubDate>Wed, 19 Jul 2017 19:43:56 +0000</pubDate>

</item>
```

Comment: One short hint: Your title is misleading. `attribute` is the correct term for a value **within** an `element`: `<TheElement TheAttribute="SomeValue" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a predicate calling `local-name()` to get this generically:

### Hint

You reduced your XML, which is great, but the remainders where not fully valid, had to correct some things (missing namespaces)...
**Have a look at the `URL` in the second feed**. the `&` sign should get you in troubles...

```
declare @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
(N'<item xmlns:dc="dummy">
                    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.espnfc.com/story/3154621/wojciech-szczesny-completes-transfer-to-juventus-from-arsenal3154621</guid>
                    <title><![CDATA[Wojciech Szczesny completes transfer to Juventus from Arsenal]]></title>

                    <description>
                        &lt;img style=&quot;float: left; margin-right: 10px;&quot; src=&quot;http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/1002/r134626_1296x729_16-9.jpg&amp;amp;w=100&amp;amp;h=80&amp;amp;scale=crop&amp;amp;site=espnfc&quot; /&gt;<![CDATA[Douglas Costa hopes to evolve as a player with Juventus and gain recognition for Brazil&apos;s World Cup squad next year. 
Juventus have completed the signing of Wojciech Szczesny from Arsenal for a fee of &amp;#8364;12.2 million.
Poland goalkeeper Szczesny underwent his medical in Turin on Tuesday and officially became a Juventus player on Wednesday in a deal that could rise to &amp;#8364;15.3 million, depending on performance.
The 27-year-old, who spent the last two seasons on loan at Roma, has signed a four-year contract for the Bianconeri, where he is expected to be understudy to Italy No. 1 Gianlugi Buffon in the coming...]]>
                    </description>

                    <link>http://www.espnfc.com/story/3154621/wojciech-szczesny-completes-transfer-to-juventus-from-arsenal</link>
                    <pubDate>Wed, 19 Jul 2017 06:19:00 PDT</pubDate>

                    <enclosure length="150" url="http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/1002/r134626_1296x729_16-9.jpg&amp;amp;w=100&amp;amp;h=80&amp;amp;scale=crop&amp;amp;site=espnfc" type="image/jpeg" />

                    <category>Story</category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Transfers]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Juventus]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Arsenal]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Wojciech Szczesny]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[English Premier League]]></category>

                    <category><![CDATA[Italian Serie A]]></category>

                    <dc:creator>Ben Gladwell</dc:creator>
                </item>')
,(N'<item xmlns:media="dummy">

<title>Sampdoria Striker Patrick Schick Could Be Set to Join Inter After Collapse of Juventus Deal</title>

<link>http://www.90min.com/posts/5285895-sampdoria-striker-patrick-schick-could-be-set-to-join-inter-after-collapse-of-juventus-deal?utm_source=RSS</link>

<author>Callum Rice-Coates</author>

<guid isPermaLink="false">d5a2ba8b504a22fcdb405ec687f91956</guid>
<description>Sampdoria striker Patrick Schick could be on the verge of a move to Inter after a proposed deal to join Juventus fell through. Ginaluca Di Marzio has reported that the Czech forward''s representatives have met with the Inter hierarchy to discuss the details of the potential transfer. According to the Italian journalist, Schick, who found the net 11 times in 32 Serie A appearances last season, ''could soon enjoy a new experience at Inter.'' #Calciomercato | #Inter, incontro in corso con la...</description>


<media:thumbnail type="image/jpg" />

<pubDate>Wed, 19 Jul 2017 19:43:56 +0000</pubDate>

</item>');
```

This is your query:

```
SELECT itm.value(N'(link/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS link
      ,itm.value(N'(title/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS title
      ,itm.value(N'(*[local-name()="creator" or local-name()="author"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS author
FROM @mockup AS m
CROSS APPLY m.YourXML.nodes(N'/item') AS A(itm)
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it using part of your code. Posted the Answer below

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting BulkColumn directly to `XML`, convert it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` first.

Then use `REPLACE` function on that string to find and replace `<dc:creator>` with `<author>` and `</dc:creator>` with `</author>`

Convert new string to XML and proceed with your SELECT FROM XML using *author* attribute

Code snippet:

```
 SET @Query ='
            DECLARE @xmlFile as XML
            DECLARE @xmlString NVARCHAR(MAX);
            SET @xmlString =(SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),BulkColumn) as BulkColumn
            FROM OPENROWSET (BULK  '''+@file+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t);

            SET @xmlString = REPLACE(@xmlString, ''<dc:creator>'', ''<author>'')
            SET @xmlString = REPLACE(@xmlString, ''</dc:creator>'', ''</author>'')
            SELECT @xmlFile = CONVERT(XML,  @xmlString);

            INSERT INTO feed.tempXML (source, title,link,author,[date])
            SELECT
            source = t.value (''../link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                title = t.value (''title[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                link = t.value (''./link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                author = t.value(''author[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)''),
                [date] = t.value(''pubDate[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)'')
            FROM @xmlFile.nodes(''/rss/channel/item'') AS xTable(t);'
```

Comment: In most cases it is a bad idea to deal with XML on string level. The casts are very expensive and several structural changes are taking place (e.g. `CDATA` sections.

Answer (score 0):

Using a line of code from @Shnugo's suggestion, I have solved the problem by replacing this part of the code:

```
author = t.value(''author[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)'')
```

With this part :

```
author = t.value(N''(*[local-name()="creator" or local-name()="author"]/text())[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)'')
```

So now query looks like this:

```
SET @Query ='
            DECLARE @xmlFile as XML
            SET @xmlFile =(SELECT CONVERT(XML,BulkColumn) as BulkColumn
            FROM OPENROWSET (BULK  '''+@file+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t)
            INSERT INTO feed.tempXML (source, title,link,author,[date])
            SELECT 
                source = t.value (''../link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                title = t.value (''title[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                link = t.value (''./link[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(300)''),
                author = t.value(N''(*[local-name()="creator" or local-name()="author"]/text())[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)''),
                [date] = t.value(''pubDate[1]'',''NVARCHAR(50)'')
            FROM @xmlFile.nodes(''/rss/channel/item'') AS xTable(t);'
```